# Interact with slack bot without a public accessible server

Tags: slack, slack-api

For some security reasons that I can't have a public accessible server to receive data from slack.

So, this is what I'm planning to do:

- Inbound message from slack: using RTM API
- Outbound message to slack: using RTM API or Web API

Questions:

1. Any better alternatives?
2. Any restrictions? (AFAIK, buttons and drop downs can't work)
3. If Web API reach rate limit, can I use incoming webhook as a backup plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### RTM only approach

Yes, that would work. With only the RTM API you are limited to:

- receiving and responding to messages
- Other [RTM events](https://api.slack.com/events).

You can't use any interactive functionality like:

- [Interactive components](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity#components) (buttons, menus, datepickers)
- [Dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs)

### Rate limit on message posting

Using the webhook as "backup" to circumvent the rate limit is not an option, since the rate limit of posting max 1 message per second applies to all form of message posting.

From the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits#limits_when_posting_messages):

> In general, apps may post no more than one message per second per
>   channel, whether a message is posted via chat.postMessage, an incoming
>   webhook, or one of the many other ways to send messages in to Slack.

### Alternatives

You did not give any details about the reasons why your app can't expose an endpoint to the public Internet. But you might want to consider using a VPN tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! As to "apps may post no more than 1 message per second per channel",  how does it applied to DMs? Say I have a bot which could possibly serve 5 users at the same time via DM, will each DM have a channel? or share 1 channel?

Comment: yes, each DM counts as its own channel. same as each private channel and public channel.

Comment: Btw, any pros and cons for RTM and Web API if I'd like to choose 1 of them to respond message back. I guess RTM might be more efficient since the connection is sitting there. Any cases (like special or complex messages) that I have to use Web API to respond rather than RTM?

Comment: You can only send simple messages over the RTM API. For anything complex, e.g. attachments or blocks you need to use the Web API. Source: https://api.slack.com/rtm#sending_messages

Comment: Btw.: If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

## Yes! Socket Mode

There is a new alternative from slack, [Socket Mode](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket), which doesn't require a publicly accessible server.

> **Note**: *this is only for private apps.*

With Socket Mode you have an API token and your server uses it to communicate with Slack's servers and create a two way socket connection. This means your Slack Bot's code can run on a machine behind a firewall and not require any inbound ports to be opened.

Slack [message delivery](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket-implement#events) requires an `acknowledgement` once you get the message, or else they [may retry](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#the-events-api__field-guide__error-handling__graceful-retries) to deliver it.

## Limitations

Socket Mode has two main limitations:

> Apps using Socket Mode are not currently allowed in the public Slack App Directory.

> Socket Mode is only available for apps using new, granular permissions. If you created your app on or after December of 2019, good news: your app already uses the new permissions. Otherwise, you may have to migrate your classic Slack app to use granular permissions before turning on Socket Mode.